# Conflict between jQuery .css() and CSS hover property

Tags: jquery, html, css, hover

basically i have 3 links and i've used hover css property to make them white/red when user enter/leave link area:

```
<div id="nav-glob">
    <ul>
        <!--menu-->
        <li class="nav-home"><a href="#content">Home</a></li>
        <li class="nav-portfolio"><a href="#lavori">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li class="nav-contact"><a href="#footer">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

.nav-glob a:hover {
    color: red;
}
```

Then in jQuery i've used `click()` function to set the css `color` property to red:

```
$('.nav-home > a').click(function(){
    $(".nav-home a").css("color", "red");
    $(".nav-contact a").css("color", "white");
    $(".nav-portfolio a").css("color", "white");
});

$('.nav-portfolio > a').click(function(){
    $(".nav-home a").css("color", "white");
    $(".nav-contact a").css("color", "white");
    $(".nav-portfolio a").css("color", "red");
});

$('.nav-contact > a').click(function(){
    $(".nav-home a").css("color", "white");
    $(".nav-contact a").css("color", "red");
    $(".nav-portfolio a").css("color", "white");
});
```

The problem is this is **working fine the first** time: after clicking one link the `hover` CSS property is ignored! It looks like that `hover` has been disabled after clicking. Any help is much appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try some CSS for differenct `a` tag states:

```
a.clicked {
    color: #f00;
}
a.hovered{
   color: #f00 !important;
}
a.faded {
    color: #fff
}


$('#nav-glob ul li a').hover(function() {
    $(this).parent().siblings('li').find('a').removeClass('hovered');
    $(this).addClass('hovered');
}, function() {
    $(this).parent().siblings('li').find('a').removeClass('hovered');
    $(this).removeClass('hovered');
}).click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#nav-glob ul li a').removeClass('faded');
    $(this).parent().siblings('li').find('a').addClass('faded');
    $(this).addClass('clicked');
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/QStkd/55/)**

or just as @Blazemonger said

```
a.faded {
    color: #fff
}
a.clicked {
    color: #f00;
}
a:hover{
   color: #f00 !important;
}

$('#nav-glob ul li a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#nav-glob ul li a').removeClass('faded');
    $(this).parent().siblings('li').find('a').addClass('faded');
    $(this).addClass('clicked');
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fLuyu/1/)**

Answer (score 2):

Try setting your `:hover` properties to `!important`, and they should override the inline styles.

Alternatively, if you don't like using `!important`, you could use `.toggleClass()` to add and remove a particular class, rather than changing the inline CSS styles directly.

Answer (score 0):

Inline-styles override stylesheet styles. This is the expected behavior. Instead of setting the color back to default, remove the style attribute so that the stylsheet is back in control.

```
$('#nav-glob a').click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.parent().siblings().children('a').removeAttr("style");
    $this.css("color", "red");
});
```